# How to save current command on zsh?

Tags: zsh, keyboard-shortcuts

I am typing a command, I remember I have to check something, if I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> the command disappears and I can type something else, but then the command I was typing is not in the history.

Is there a way to recover that command, or a different shortcut that I can press to save somewhere the command?

Comment: Another way to solve that would be to have a tabbed terminal. Just open a new tab.

Comment: @EmanuelBerg I know, I asked this question so I could stop doing that, I use guake and it is impossible to see which tab is open.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> will paste the last item you cut (with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, etc.).

Comment: ...And `Alt + y' will cycle though all you previously yanked

Comment: Thanks a bunch! `Ctrl+K` and `Alt+Y` didn't work on zsh 5.0.0 (Ubuntu 13.04 x86_64).

Comment: @michelpm: Yeah? Try `zsh --version`. I have `zsh 4.3.17 (i686-pc-linux-gnu)` and it works for me. (Edit: Oh. That's what you did.)

Answer (score 13):

Take a look at the `push-line` ZLE command. This command pushes the current contents of the line onto the buffer stack and clears the line. You can then enter another command and when ZLE starts up again, the line is popped from the buffer stack into the line buffer.

```
prompt@world$ cp abc /mnt/usr/bin       # The user presses Esc-q
prompt@world$                           # The line is cleared
prompt@world$ mount -v /dev/sdb1 /mnt   # And the user can enter another command
mount: /dev/sdb1 mounted on /mnt
prompt@world$ cp abc /mnt/usr/bin
# The first command is popped off of the stack
#  as soon as ZLE comes back.
```

By default, this command is bound to <kbd>Alt</kbd>/<kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>q</kbd> in emacs mode. You can bind this command to a different key with the `bindkey` command. For example, in order to bind it to <kbd>Alt</kbd>/<kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>, add `bindkey '^[V' push-line` to your `zshrc`.

Comment: Liked this one even better! Comment something so I can upvote you again ;D

Comment: Thank you, but upvotes on comments don't give reputation points.

Comment: I was just kidding, didn't notice I was blinking? ;D

Answer (score 6):

You're looking for the [`push-line`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#index-push_002dline) command, which is bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> and <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>Q</kbd> by default. This command clears the input and lets you enter another command; once you've executed or canceled this command, the previous command is brought back for editing.

With a multiline command , `push-line` only clears the current line, and keeps the other lines in the input buffer. There is another command [`push-input`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#index-push_002dinput) which clears the whole input buffer, not bound to any key by default.

I use a wrapper around this command. I type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to “suspend” the command I'm typing and type another command. After I've run that command (or aborted it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>), the suspended command comes back for edition (even remembering the cursor position). As an additional convenience, if the command line is empty when I type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, the key invokes the `bg` built-in instead (so a double <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> sends a running command directly to the background).

```
fancy-ctrl-z () {
  emulate -LR zsh
  if [[ $#BUFFER -eq 0 ]]; then
    bg
    zle redisplay
  else
    zle push-input
  fi
}
zle -N fancy-ctrl-z
bindkey '^Z'          fancy-ctrl-z
```

A low-tech method that works in any shell is to add a `#` at the beginning of the current line and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Adding to the last comment, need this for that to work well: `setopt interactive_comments`, and still that goes to history unless put also a space in front and have declared `setopt hist_ignore_space`. I still like the `push-line` thing, but the `ctrl+z` does not work for the line I'm typing.

Comment: @michelpm Oh, right, you need `setopt interactive_comments` in zsh. Entering the line in the history is the point, if you don't then the line is lost forever. The version of `fancy-ctrl-z` I posted works for me under `zsh -f`, it may be conflicting with a setting in your `.zshrc` though I don't see what.

Comment: The way I said I can still recover as if it was in the history, but it doesn't get persisted in the history, I can not recover after I close the shell. It is just a detail, but it is useful, because you don't want to store garbage or secrets there.

Comment: Your `fancy-ctrl-z` does work, ignore my first comment.

Comment: +1 for mentioning `pos1 + # + enter`